# SliverAppbar has a bluish tint

Tags: flutter, dart, sliverappbar

I have used a SliverAppBar in a widget for which the code is as follows;

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            floating: false,
            snap: false,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
            elevation: 1,
            expandedHeight: 100.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/content/Update.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Item #$index')),
              childCount: 1000,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My themedata has been configured to look like this;

```dart
final theme = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
    seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 41, 41, 41),
    primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 41, 41, 41),
    primaryContainer: const Color.fromARGB(20, 41, 41, 41),
    secondary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 80, 80, 80),
    background: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
  ),
  textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(),
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
  ),
  splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
);
```

When I scroll, the SliverAppBar has this strange bluish tint to it which I cannot understand why or how is coming. I want the appbar to have the color of the background or just be "transparent" so that it looks like part of the entire page as a single unit. Currently it looks like a different thing compared to the entire page.

[image] [image]

The other workaround would be to create a custom appbar which would be "fixed" to the top when scrolling is detected but I want to go with the appbar approach.

Comment: @OMiShah, 
from the docs:
`a is the alpha value, with 0 being transparent and 255 being fully opaque.`
`r is [red], from 0 to 255.`
`g is [green], from 0 to 255.`
`b is [blue], from 0 to 255.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because Material transparency which you are specifying is in itself set to false by default in all AppBars and Sliver AppBars while they are being scrolled.

To remove them, set

```
forceMaterialTransparency: true
```

It will definetly work. Let me know if it doesn't :)
And please mark the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes, it works. I tried it on a test widget and it made the whole thing transparent so I was trying to sort that out. But thanks, this works.

Comment: Welcome Anuj, lemme know if you have any additional issues related to Slivers :)